# How to combine two records?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
ID | Value | Type
-----------------------
1  | 50    | Travel
1  | 25    | Non-Travel
1  | 25    | Non-Travel
1  | 25    | Non-Travel
1  | 50    | Travel
1  | 75    | Non-Travel
```

How can I query this to make the output rearrange to this?

```
ID | Travel | Non-Travel
------------------------
1  | 100    | 150
```

The query to actually get the first table I posted has many joins and a BIT column in one of the tables where 0 or NULL is non-travel and 1 is travel. So I have something like this:

```
SELECT 
    [ID]
    ,CASE WHEN [IsTravel] IN (0,NULL) THEN ISNULL(SUM([VALUE]),0) END  AS 'NonTravel'
    ,CASE WHEN [IsTravel] = 1 THEN ISNULL(SUM([VALUE]),0) END  AS 'Travel'
FROM
    ...
```

However the result ends up showing this

```
ID | Travel | Non-Travel
------------------------
1  | 100    | NULL
1  | NULL   | 150
```

How can I edit my query to combine the rows to show this result?

```
ID | Travel | Non-Travel
------------------------
1  | 100    | 150
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could run a group by on the result. Select Id, SUM(Travel),SUM([Non-Travel]) FROM (<yourquery>) GROUP BY Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select ID,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Travel' THEn value ELSE 0  END) [Travel],
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'NonTravel' THEn value ELSE 0  END) [NonTravel] 
 from  @Table1
    GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Nice! Simply and clean. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap each of your conditionals in aggregations such as `MAX()`, and `GROUP BY` other columns to roll up the values and remove the `NULL`.  Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    [ID]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN [IsTravel] IN (0,NULL) THEN ISNULL(SUM([VALUE]),0) END)  AS 'NonTravel'
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN [IsTravel] = 1 THEN ISNULL(SUM([VALUE]),0) END)  AS 'Travel'
FROM
    ...
GROUP BY [ID]
```

If the logic gets too cluttered or confusing (don't know without seeing your whole current query) then drop those results into a temp table or CTE and do the simple `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivot as below:

```
 Select * from (
    Select Id, [Value], [Type] from yourtable ) a
 pivot (sum([Value]) for [Type] in ([Travel],[Non-Travel]) ) p
```

Output as below:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| Id | Non-Travel | Travel |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 |        150 |    100 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

For dynamic list of Travel types you can do dynamic query as below:

```
Declare @cols1 varchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols1 = stuff((select Distinct ','+QuoteName([Type]) from #traveldata for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Set @query = '  Select * from (
    Select Id, [Value], [Type] from #traveldata ) a
 pivot (sum([Value]) for [Type] in (' + @cols1 + ') ) p '

Exec sp_executesql @query
```